# str_replace in SQL UPDATE?

Tags: sql, mysql, string

Here's a sample table:

```
name       |   picture

John S.    |   http://servera.host.com/johns.png
Linda B.   |   http://servera.host.com/lindab.png
...
```

Let's say there are several hundred more records.

Let's also say we moved servers from "servera" to "serverb".

Would it be possible to go into this table with *one query* to rename the content in the column "picture" for every record to read the correct server name?

Comment: Yes, on almost every database engine it would be possible to do this with a single UPDATE query.  Since you don't specify a particular product, however, you're likely only to get answers for whatever someone's favorite product is.  Let us know what you're using and someone will reply with the syntax for that product.

Comment: Oh, that's true - thanks, Larry. I'd forgotten to mention that I am developing on MySQL

Comment: This is more of an architectural sticking point than answering your question directly, but I would suggest not storing the FQDN of the url in your database. Keep that as a constant in your application code, and then when you draw a link to your picture the src will combine the PIC_HOST_DOMAIN_NAME.'/johns.png'. This makes it much easier to move your images around, as well as use a CDN as a CNAME sitting in front of your images.

Comment: Hi David - I agree that that is the easiest and best way to go. Our more recent applications support just this philosophy, but our legacy apps do not. Hence the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

T-SQL:

```
update TBL 
   set picture = Replace(picture, 'servera', 'serverb') 
 where picture like '%servera%'
```

Oracle:

```
update TBL 
   set picture = replace(picture, 'servera', 'serverb') 
 where picture like '%servera%'
```

MySQL:

```
update TBL 
   set picture = REPLACE(picture, 'servera', 'serverb') 
 where picture like '%servera%'
```

Answer (score 20):

```
UPDATE users
SET picture = REPLACE(picture, 'http://servera.host.com/', 'http://serverb.host.com/')
WHERE picture LIKE 'http://servera.host.com/%';
```

I'm including more of the string because I'd worry about 'fixing' an image named 'somethingserverasomething.jpg'. I might also think about having a base_url table and just storing image file names in users, but that's not the question you asked ;-)