# SQL statement to remove part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [str_replace in SQL UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944000/str-replace-in-sql-update)
>   [How to remove part of string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481361/how-to-remove-part-of-string-in-mysql)
>   [SQL Find & Replace part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153852/sql-find-replace-part-of-a-string)

I have a database table with a list of website urls e.g. `http://website.com/` and I want to remove all the `http://` and `https://` from them. Is their a simple SQL statement I could run on a column to remove it?

I've had a search around, but I can't find what I need. I'm presuming I need to use both REPLACE and UPDATE but I'm struggling.

So far I have:

```
UPDATE list
SET    website
WHERE  website LIKE 'http://%';
```

Is that correct? I'm using MySQL and the table is list, and column is website and I want to remove the `http://` so a url like: `http://website.com/` becomes just: `website.com`

**EDIT: Is it also possible to remove a trailing slash as well?**

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481361/how-to-remove-part-of-string-in-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068229/sql-deleting-replacing-a-part-of-a-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153852/sql-find-replace-part-of-a-string

Comment: use str_replace function with update query

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have a look at the `REPLACE` function.  You'll need to use it twice to remove both http and https.

```
UPDATE    list
SET       website = REPLACE(REPLACE(website, 'https://', ''), 'http://', '')
WHERE     website like 'https://%' 
  OR      website like 'http://%'
```

To handle trailing slashes, you can use the `RIGHT`, `LEFT`, and `LENGTH` functions.

```
UPDATE    list
SET       website = LEFT(website, LENGTH(website) - 1)
WHERE     RIGHT(website, 1) = '/'
```

Here is some documentation that you may find useful:
[MySQL string functions](http://w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-ascii-function.php)

Comment: Is it possible to remove trailing slashes using this method?

Answer (score 15):

Why not just replace the string if it exists:

```
UPDATE list
SET    website = Replace(website, 'http://', '')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’) where CONDITION
```