# Delete some characters from a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have ONE column in MySQl table which contains this format:

https://open.spotify.com/track/AAABBBCCC

and I'd like to leave just AAABBBCCC, and not the entire column! The last parte is always the same.

Is that possible? Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: substring may be an option https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) to delete the wanted text from your column:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 =  REPLACE(Column1,'https://open.spotify.com/track/','')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL REPLACE function to do that.

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET your_column_name = REPLACE(your_column_name, 'https://open.spotify.com/track/', '')
```

For more information you can read [SQL statement to remove part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030143/sql-statement-to-remove-part-of-a-string)